# IE compatibility mode issue

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

My problem is that IE8 goes in Compatibility Mode on some computers (So far the computers on our companys domain only).

We've had the problem before, only difference is that it went into Compatibility Mode on all computers, so I added this tag as the first element in my `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

And it fixed it on some computers. Could this be an IE option set by our admins, or does anyone have any other idea of what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the X-UA-Compatible as a HTTP header, and not as a meta tag.